# PHP Imagick: How to resize without scaling up?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am using PHP Imagick to manipulate images.

I have two use cases: "resize" and "crop".

In the "resize", if the original image's dimensions are less than the given width and the height, I **do not want** Imagick to scale it up and instead want it to simply return the original size.

However, as the PHP documentation says, the behavior of Imagick has been changed from version 3 (I am using version 6+) that it would always scale up the image.

> Note: The behavior of the parameter bestfit changed in Imagick 3.0.0.
>   Before this version given dimensions 400x400 an image of dimensions
>   200x150 would be left untouched. In Imagick 3.0.0 and later the image
>   would be scaled up to size 400x300 as this is the "best fit" for the
>   given dimensions. If bestfit parameter is used both width and height
>   must be given.

So, in my case, for given dimensions 400x400, an image of dimensions 200x150 should return an image of 200x150 not 400x300. For given dimensions 100x100 an image of dimensions 200x150 should return an image of 100x75 (that is scaling down should happen).

I tried thumbnailImage(), resizeImage() and scaleImage() without any luck.
If I set bestfit to false it does the cropping, which is not what I want with resize.

Is there any way to get this done with Imagick?

Comment: *"version 6+"* is not a useful statement to indicate your version; *"version 6.9.1-3*" would be... So please, give the output of `convert -version`.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that my version is greater than 3.0 and I am affected by the changed behavior.

Following is the convert -version output:

Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP

Comment: why not just write some code that does exactly what you want with http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagewidth.php

Comment: @Danack That function simply returns the image width. I am not sure how to write this resize functionality with plain PHP (not sure whether it's even possible) and I want to stick to Imagick (kind of a requirement) and do not want to use GD.

Answer (score 12):

Try to do that way:

```
$max_width  = 1200;
$max_height = 800;
$im = new Imagick($path_to_image);
$im->resizeImage(
    min($im->getImageWidth(),  $max_width),
    min($im->getImageHeight(), $max_height),
    imagick::FILTER_CATROM,
    1,
    true
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this command:

```
convert input.img -resize 400x400\> output.img
```

Note the specific way of giving the wanted dimension with the appended `\>` modifier: it tells the conversion process to only resize images that are *larger* than 400x400 pixels. Images which are smaller stay un-touched.

Comment: I do not want this to be done via the command line (or via PHP's exec()). I wanted to know whether there is a way in PHP Imagick class. After resizing, I will pass the object to other methods for further manipulations like watermarking.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Imagick != ImageMagick. The command line version of ImageMagick does a whole load of stuff that isn't exposed through the API that Imagick has access to.